# Why there is a boost in the after hours trading?

Tags: stocks, after-hours-trading

I noticed that there is a boost peak in the after-hours trading for TWTR. Why is that happening?

[image][image]

Comment: Read here http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/081514/what-are-main-risks-afterhours-trading.asp

Comment: The order was reported by FINRA and is marked as exempt from Rule 611. There are a number of reasons why this may be the case, such as the correction of a trade error for example. It doesn't look like an order that went through the market.